# How to claim a url that has not been taken?

Tags: linux, hosting, tld

I have a little bit of knowledge on hosting apache web servers running php using  linux, and I do not want to buy a DNS from anyone, is it possible to claim an unused domain such as http://asdeygxzbuhdqewrfducyh.com/? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can "claim" an URL and configure it in your Apache. However, nobody else will know it. If you don't want people to have to refer to your page by IP address, you need a DNS name for your page. Some DNS names are cheaper than others, and some are free.

Comment: But how could i get one that no one owns, like I don't know, http://www.dfedixcfhnrwjedfxyfhuievdxcyduhifjd.com

Comment: They same way as any other free domain. Find a registrar that suits you and register the domain. Some are cheaper, some provide better service. You should be able to get a domain for $10-$20 a year.

Comment: But how do the registrar's get the domain?

Comment: @DMVerfurth see this question for how Domain Registrars work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235607/how-does-domain-registration-work